# Reading arrays from .txt file as numbers instead of strings

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

I'm using an automatic data acquisition software that exports the data as .txt files. I then imported the file into python (using the pandas package and turning the columns into arrays) but I'm facing a problem. Python can't "read" the data because the automatic data acquisition software exported it into the following number format, and so Python is treating each entry of the array as a string instead of a number:

[image: Printscreen of the data]

Is there any way I can "teach" python to read my data? Or to automatically rewrite the entries in the array so they're read as numbers?

Comment: Please show what you have tried?

Comment: How, exactly, are you using pandas here?

Comment: ```number = float('7,025985E-36'.replace(',', '.'))``` and then ```print({:.50f}".format(number))``` will give you the whole number

Comment: `df['Sine(Power Spectrum)']=df['Sine(Power Spectrum)'].str.replace(',','.').astype(float)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply change the comma in the strings with a dot and use `float()` to parse it.

```
number = float('7,025985E-36'.replace(',', '.'))

print(number)
print(type(number))
```

The above code would print:

```
7.025985e-36
<class 'float'>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way.

```
>>> value=str('7,025985e-36')
>>> value2=value.replace(',', '.')
>>> float(value2)
7.025985e-36
```